# Storing client-side data within a signed java applet

Tags: java, cookies, applet, signed

I'm trying to store some data from a java applet so I can read it later with the same applet. For example I want the user to input a username during the first execution of my applet and save it somewhere so that on the following runs of my applet it can recover it.

In javascript I'll just write my data in document.cookie following a key=param pattern but I didn't find anything like that in Java.

Is there a simple way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

["Accessing Cookies" in "The Java Tutorials"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/accessingCookies.html) will help you...

Comment: I did see this before posting but I really don't understand why I would need the 'url' things : I don't want to get my cookie from an URL or send it to the server, I am just looking to use persistent client-side data.

Comment: From the pop-up on the info. tag for cookies. *"An HTTP cookie is a piece of data stored by the user's web browser."*  - where would the browser store it, if not 'client side'?

Comment: I agree with you Andrew that's why I thought of cookies and tagged it. I just don't really get the url thing, I guess I'll just put some random address.

Comment: I tried again and no it didn't help me. It looks like the CookieStore can only retrieve remote cookies from a web page  and I can never get the cookies I put using the 'Setting Cookies' paragraph. Not even if I just did add them with my signed applet with the url of the page hosting the applet or the one of the applet itself.